# How can I insert html code to Jquery Dialog Container in Zend framework Jquery Form

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, jquery-ui-dialog, zendx

I'm currently working Zend framework and placing Zendx_Jquery_Form in Jquery Dialog Container

Just wanted to know is there a way to insert html code (so i can put a picture in there) to the Jquery Dialog Container in zend framework.

This is my code to declare my Zend form in Jquery Dialog Container

```
 public function setSubFormDecorators(Zend_Form_SubForm $subForm)
    {

           $subForm->setDecorators(array(
                       'FormElements',
                        'Form',
                             array('DialogContainer', array(
                                 'title' => 'MY FORM',
                                 'id' => 'tabContainer',
                    'jQueryParams' => array(

                                 'width' => auto,
                                 'height' => auto,
                                 'draggable' => true,
                                 'resizable' => false,
                                 'position' => 'middle',
                                 'zIndex' => 80
                    ),
               )),
            ));
        return $this;

    }
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.form.html);

> The only use for the Dialog Container
>   in Zend Form context is to wrap itself
>   around a form and display it in a
>   dialog.

You could either create the form without the DialogContainer, and provide the form html to the [DialogContainer view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.view.html) and throw your own html/images into the mix

**or**

you could use the DialogContainer in the Zend_Form context as a container, and add the image as a form element, as [Zend_Form_Element_Image](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html).